# PHP - Retrieve via $_POST the hidden input's value between several others

Tags: php, html, get, submit

I have a `table` that is in a `foreach` loop, and every iteration the hidden `input` receives the ID from the database. My table has in each column an `input` field because I'd like to edit the data from the database right in the table, and to make it happen I had to put a submit `button` that when clicked retrieves the ID from the hidden `input` into another file that then does the operation.

```
<form action="../php/Operations.php" method="post">
//...
<?php foreach ($Service->select() as $col) { ?>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $col["id"]; ?>" name="id"/>
//...
```

The problem is that the `$_POST` value is always the very first from the table, because there are *n* hidden `input` with the same name.

I'd like to know if there is a way to retrieve the hidden `input`'s value from the clicked row, having in mind I'm not using `$_GET`, but a submit `button`,

`<button type="submit" name="submit" value="update" class="btn_action">Editar</button>`

that when clicked is supose to execute the code I wrote:

```
switch($_REQUEST["submit"]) {
    case "update":
        $ServiceDatabase->update($_POST["id"]);
        break;
//...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want multiple inputs with the same name use `name="id[]"` for the input name attribute. `$_POST` will then contain an array for name with all values from the input elements. Then you can then loop over this array.

Example:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="foo"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="bar"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="baz"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

PHP

```
$ids= $_POST['id'];
print_r($ids);
```

---

**EDIT:** You can change your code like this so each submit button is tied to exactly one hidden input with the `name="id"`.

```
<?php foreach ($Service->select() as $col) { ?>
    <form action="../php/Operations.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $col["id"]; ?>" name="id"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="update" class="btn_action">Editar</button>
    </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<form action="../php/Operations.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="1234" name="id"/><button type="submit" name="submit" value="update" class="btn_action">Editar</button></form>
<form action="../php/Operations.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="5678" name="id"/><button type="submit" name="submit" value="update" class="btn_action">Editar</button></form>
<form action="../php/Operations.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" value="9101112" name="id"/><button type="submit" name="submit" value="update" class="btn_action">Editar</button></form>
```

Comment: I see. But the issue is that I need to call only the `input` from the clicked row. Like this, won't all of them be retrieved?

Comment: You will have to supply more code. There are no clickable rows in the code in your question, just hidden inputs.

Comment: By "clicked row" I mean the submit of the row. Each row has a submit `button` that when clicked is suppose to perform the update operation passing the ID via `$_POST`.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't do any difference. The problem lays on the attribute name, that since there are a lot of hidden `input` with the same name, the script will always retrieve the first one on the list, no matter what submit I click.

Comment: In my edit, there is only one hidden input named "id" per form. It isn't possible for other hidden inputs in different forms to interfere. Is there more you are doing?

Comment: Yes, I have a `foreach` inside of the `form`, but now, I put the whole form inside of the loop, and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend you to use ajax for submitting the data

Just create a click event in for the button and get the button id

in your htm form create an id attribute like this

```
<input type="hidden" id="colId<?php echo $col["id"]; ?>" value="<?php echo $col["id"]; ?>" />
```

and your button should look like this

```
<button class="buttonSubmit" id="<?php echo $col["id"]; ?>" >Submit</button>
$(".buttonSubmit").click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   var hiddeninput = $("colId"+id).val();
   // here you can process how would you send the data to a php file 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either wrap each col in a separate form and have a separate submit button per col or make the name attribute an array. i.e. `name="id[<?php echo htmlspecialchars($id); ?>"`

Comment: Alright, I put the name attribute an array, but how can I call it with `$_POST` variable in the `Operations.php` file?

Comment: The $_POST[$id] variable is now an array, you can iterate it with foreach, and use whatever method to look up the related data that you were planning to use anyway.

Comment: I see. But the issue is that I need to call only the input from the clicked submit of one row. Like this, won't all of them be retrieved?

Comment: Yup, either you pull in all the inputs in your form and sort it out server side, or you wrap each set in a separate form and submit only what you want. The latter can be done with js if you don't want to generate the markup serverside but you'd have to add a lot more detail to your question for me to help you there.